# In Angular why will the HTML body of my component not show?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

I can navigate to the component just fine, and the header/sidebar load fine, and even the component typescript works correctly.

But none of the HTML is displaying. This is specifically for the `dashboard/:id` route.

Any ideas?

`app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './views/dashboard/dashboard.component';

// Import Containers
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './containers';

// AuthGaurd
import { IdguardGuard as IdAuthGaurd } from './idguard.guard';
import { AdminGuard as AdminGuard } from './admin.guard';
import { ClientgaurdGuard as ClientAuthGaurd } from './clientgaurd.guard';


export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard/:id',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [IdAuthGaurd, ClientAuthGaurd]
      },
      {
        path: 'base',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./views/base/base.module').then((m) => m.BaseModule),
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
}),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting to `home` but you don't have `home` path in the same level:

Change it to:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard/:id',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [IdAuthGaurd, ClientAuthGaurd]
      },
      {
        path: 'base',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./views/base/base.module').then((m) => m.BaseModule),
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And the navigate to `/home/dashboard/:id`.

Or:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard/:id',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [IdAuthGaurd, ClientAuthGaurd]
      },
      {
        path: 'base',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./views/base/base.module').then((m) => m.BaseModule),
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This will work with no change in navigation. Just navigate to `/dashboard/:id`.

Comment: I tried your option 2 and it still does not display anything in the HTML portion. Is there any other files I should add to my post for help? I have a very similar routing/html setup in another app and it works fine.

Comment: what route are you navigation to? tell me that line syntax. @user68288

Comment: http://localhost/#/dashboard/1 -- would prefer to get rid of the "#". I am a novice, my apologies.

Comment: you should route like this: `this.router.navigate(['', 'dashboard', id]);` @user68288